# C# removing a line of text from textfile using textbox

Tags: c#

**Can C# replace a single line of text in a text file with the user's input from a textbox?**

My text file has multiple strings with the same name "Ang Mo Kio"

My program is supposed to be a bike rental company, renting bikes to customers. I have a requirement to show the location. The default location is set as "Ang mo kio", so I used `StreamWriter` to write it into a text file.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter location = new StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\Mb.txt", true); 
    location.WriteLine(textBox7.Text);
    location.Close();
 }
```

And linked it with my combobox so that when I click the combobox index it will show the location from the textbox according to readlines.

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
    string filename = ("C:\\temp\\Mb.txt");
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

    textBox2.Text = (lines[comboBox1.SelectedIndex]);
}
```

Now I'm trying to rent out the bike, but  when I click on a button after choosing an index in combobox1, I deleted the index so that next customer can't rent it out.

```
string X;

int index;
index = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
if (index != -1)
{
    X = comboBox1.Items[index].ToString();
    comboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
}


using (StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\MountainBike.txt"))
{
    foreach (var item in comboBox1.Items)
    {
        sw1.WriteLine(item);
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

Now the main problem is my location remained the same and I can't remove a line from what is shown in the textbox, and it remains in my text file.

i tried using `StreamWriter` to overwrite it but it just removes all lines - not a single line.

Comment: Your english is making this _very_ hard to follow, Are you trying to remove lines in a text file based on the index specified by a combo box? Can you tell us the end goal of your program here and where the difficulty is?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't keep your location data in memory instead of writing it to a file every time? It would make this much easier and simpler if you didn't write to files?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question mostly to improve grammar and code formatting. The big change was re-writing your original question in a form that I thought more people would understand. If you have more clarification, you're welcome to re-visit and improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would have realized it a little different from the start, here is a suggestion how you can hack a solution into your structure.

Take the text from the text box and split it in the single lines:

```
List<string> allLines = textBox2.Text.Split('\n').ToList();
```

now use the same index from the selection of the combobox to delete the text in the list (if I recall, the order is the same?=!)

```
X = comboBox1.Items[index].ToString();
comboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
allLines.RemoveAt(index);
```

and plug the Text back again in

```
textBox2.Text = String.Join("\n", allLines);
```

EDIT:

Probably a much better solution would be to load the file as a `List<string>`

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename).ToList();
```

this would allow you to use the selected index of the combobox to remove the lines directly at the source and write it immediately into the file back again. This way you would have an updated source and you can keep using the index from the combobox (because `lines` and combobox will have the same items as aI understood) Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
comboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
lines.RemoveAt(index);
textBox2.Text = (lines[comboBox1.SelectedIndex]);
```